# How to run python files (.py) generated by gnu-radio companion independently (without GRC GUI)?

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, gnu, gnuradio-companion

I am trying to run the python file generated by GNU Radio Companion (GRC) without using GRC GUI (from Pycharm IDE). I also set the interpreter accordingly, where the gnu radio has been installed (C:\Program Files\GNURadio-3.8\gr-python27\python.exe). But I am getting this below error still:

```
    "C:\Program Files\GNURadio-3.8\gr-python27\python.exe" "C:/Users/thangaraj/GNU Radio/AM_Demod.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/thangaraj/GNU Radio/AM_Demod.py", line 10, in <module>
    from gnuradio import gr
ImportError: No module named gnuradio
```

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Regards,
Thangaraj

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the title

> How to run python files (.py) generated by gnu-radio companion independently (without GRC GUI)?

is:

GRC just generates a python script that you can execute. You don't need the GRC UI to execute that at all.

---

The answer to the question you're asking is:

of course you need GNU Radio as is; you've not set up the paths to the GNU Radio Python modules correctly, which is why Python can't find the `gnuradio` module, exactly as the error message. You want to look into how the link/script that you use to start GRC does that, especially setting the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.